# Robocopy getting access denied but Copy isn't

Tags: network-share, robocopy, roaming-profile

For Offline work purposes, I was asked to copy users Network drive to their local machines and then from that point forward keep the two sync'd up.

I am having a weirdly hard time even starting this venture as Robocopy is hitting Error 5 Access Denied for any and all files in the users network drive, but if I do Copy   There are no problems and it copies fine. I just want to use Robocopy to save bandwidth by not copying existing files really.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the switches?

Comment: Offline Files would be a better solution for this. With your current solution how do you intend to keep the local and network files in sync? Are you going to run Robocopy every day? Every hour? Robocopy doesn't perform a bidirectional sync, so you'll need two sync jobs for each user, each sync job syncing in the opposite direction of the other sync job.

Comment: robocopy F:\ %UserProfile%\Documents\ /s

Comment: We tried Offline Files, we got very unexpected behavior. When we tried to do Offline Files of a single folder on the users network drive. The rest of the network drive would vanish until Offline Files were turned off.